# Count the number of non-NaN values in each row of a 2D array

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a matrix like this:

```
A = [1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN;
     1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,    7,    NaN,  NaN,  NaN;
     1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,    7,    8,    9,    10]
```

I would like to know how I can count the number of values in each row excluding any `NaN`s.
So I would get an output like:

```
output = [5;
          7;
          10;]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `A` is a 2D array, e.g.

```
A = [1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN,  NaN;
     1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,    7,    NaN,  NaN,  NaN;
     1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,    7,    8,    9,    10]
```

and you want to count the number of `NaN` entries on each row of `A`, you can simply use

```
>> sum(~isnan(A), 2)

ans =
   5
   7
  10
```

### Breakdown

1. `isnan(A)` returns a logical array of the same size as `A`, in which (logical`1` indicates a `NaN` and `0` a non-`NaN`.

   Note that you *have* to use the `isnan` function, here. In particular, the expression `A == ~NaN` is useless: it would simply return a logical array of the same size as `A` but full of (logical) `0`'s. Why? Because, according to floating-point arithmetic, `NaN == NaN` always returns "false" (i.e. logical `0`, in MATLAB).
2. Then, by applying MATLAB's not operator (`~`) to that, you get a logical array of the same size as `A`, in which `1` indicates a non-`NaN` and `0` a `NaN`.
3. Finally, `sum(~isnan(A), 2)` returns a column vector in which the i-th entry corresponds to the number of logical `1`'s on the i-th row of `~isnan(A)`.

The resulting column vector is exactly what you want: a count, row by row, of the non-`NaN` entries in `A`.

Comment: sum(A<=inf,2) also works, since NaN<=inf is false. Not that this is clearer, but it does it without the isnan function.

Comment: @JoeSerrano True! That would work. But yes, `isnan` is clearer.